# How to lookup an HBase table efficiently

Tags: hbase

I have a HBase lookup table where I store some information. I have a MapReduce program which runs some Pentaho KTRs and in the MapReduce job I capture the output. From certain fields in the output of the KTRs, I retrieve some keys and using them I have to lookup some values in HBase. My scenario is:

```
1. The rowkey is of format <Table Code>-<CRC>, ex- DDVC-XXX

For each output of the KTRs:    

2. If no result is found for a particular key(which I get from the Pentaho KTRs), 
    then increment a column value which has the rowkey of format
    <Table Code>-last, ex: DDVC-last
3. Take this incremented value and put it in the HBase table with the specific key.
```

So, here I am doing one Get, one Increment and one Put operation if I could not find a value for a rowkey. Can someone give me some suggestion on how to do it efficiently and without hitting HBase over again over again. Because, I can see the majority of the time the job requires is for executing the above algorithm, which hits HBase multiple times for a single row.

Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

Although the schema design may merit some attention, the problem as you described it may not be further improved performance-wise.  The Get, Increment, and Put are separate operations and do require three separate HBase calls.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. But is there any way that I can do it in a batch rather then executing Get, Incr and Put for each key? Or can I do it using the Observer co-processors, like in the postGet method?

Comment: ah! good question - in fact I am upvoting now ;)  It's late, i'll think on that..